# Is it possible to auto filter excel using selenium webdriver java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to autofilter the excel cells using selenium webdriver. I searched in google but I didn't find any suggestions is there any possibilities to autofilter the excel. If its possible, can anyone help on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Selenium Webdriver is used to drive a browser, not Excel.

Comment: Nope, you cannot use WebDriver. Just use some Java Excel Library to read data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this aspose.cells
It will create a new excel and apply filter.
See if this helps. I am also researching for applying filters in an existing file.
I will reply again if I get to know.